# Consulta sobre git

Tags: git, github

Tengo un repositorio remoto https://github.com/xxxx/yyy.git

En el mismo host donde estoy ubicado habia creado la repo y pusheado , me pidio el nick y password y pude pushear.

Clono la repo https://github.com/xxxx/yyy.git  en el mismo host ,modifico algunas cosas y pusheo (pero no me pide password ni user ,quiero que si me pida password y user).

Con esto ultimo que deberia hacer para que me pida el password y usuario ,para evitar ese tipo de inconvenientes.

Answer (score 1):

¿Agregaste una llave ssh? Si es así, simplemente deberías cambiar la url del repositorio remoto, y usar la opción https.

[image: Click en 'use HTTPS']

Para cambiar el remoto simplemente deberias correr el comando:

> git remote set-url 'nueva-url'

Answer (score 0):

Si tipeas `git config -l`, ¿ves una `credential.xxxxx`? Si es así el que no te pida credenciales se puede deber a [CredentialHelper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).

Si miras el archivo `.git/config` quizás encuentres una línea así, que indica que se está haciendo uso de CredentialHelper en ese repo.

```
[credential "https://github.com/user/turepo"]
helper = store
```